# Install only if external file exists

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to instruct Inno Setup to install a certain external file only if does exist.

Like so:

```
Source: "d:\sources\SomeDLL.dll"; DestDir: {app}; \
    Flags: external regserver uninsneveruninstall ignoreversion
```

However, I did not find a flag that would instruct Inno Setup to skip this line / file if `d:\sources\SomeDLL.dll` does not exist.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`skipifsourcedoesntexist` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=skipifsourcedoesntexist):

> This flag instructs the compiler -- or Setup, if the `external` flag is also used -- to silently skip over the entry if the source file does not exist, instead of displaying an error message.

Answer (score -1):

Try this flag:

**onlyifdestfileexists**

Only install the file if a file of the same name already exists on the user's system. This flag may be useful if your installation is a patch to an existing installation, and you don't want files to be installed that the user didn't already have.

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection