# Create INI file if not exist and write a value

Tags: inno-setup

I copy an INI-file from `{src}` to `{app}` during the installation with use of the `external` flag, then I add a key to that file.

If the file does not exist in `{src}`, it should be created (then a key should be added) in the `{app}`.

Is it possible to "Create if not exist" inside the `[Files]` or `[INI]` or I definitely have to do it in the code-section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[INI]` section automatically creates the INI file, if it does not exist yet. So you have no problem there.

For `[Files]` section, see
[Install only if external file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37163013/850848).

---

So in the end, your script should be as simple as:

```
[Files]
Source: "{src}\MyProg.ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist

[INI]
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.ini"; Section: "Section"; Key: "Key"; String: "Value"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly, what I needed :)